# Meaning of 羽目になる

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions

I have found that 羽目になる means: 
to get stuck with (some job); to end up with (something unpleasant)

But I cannot make sense of it for the following sentence

The context is of a veteran police inspector giving some advice to a new recruit on her first case.

> あんたが教わってきた事柄は全て‌理詰めのセオリーだ‌ それがどれだけ無意味なもんか‌ すぐに思い知る**羽目になる**だろさ‌
>   まあ覚悟だけはしておくんだな‌
>
> Everything you've been taught is based on theories and logic.‌ Soon,
>   you'll likely come to realize how pointless they are. Well, at least
>   be prepared.

Note: it is about the same sentence as one I used in another question ([Specificity of the use of 事柄](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74877/specificity-of-the-use-of-%e4%ba%8b%e6%9f%84)) , but for a different word

Comment: That is exactly the meaning of ending up with something unpleasant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "end up".

> それがどれだけ無意味なもんかすぐに思い知る羽目になるだろさ‌
>   You'll soon end up realizing how meaningless they (=things you've learned) are.

Here "realizing how meaningless they are" is something unpleasant to the listener.